# Find a real $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ (other than $A = I$ ) such that $A^5 = I $.

Tags: linear-algebra

I found the question in an online a source of challenging linear algebra problems, unfortunately there are no answers.

Question: Find a real $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ (other than $A = I$ ) such that $A^5 = I$.

I'm beginning to think no such matrix exists, but the way the question is posed it doesn't seem they would pull a trick like that.

Comment: Think rotations...

Comment: I'm thinking, but I'm thrown off by the odd-power. Though if 6 people up-voted you must on to something, so I'll think some more.

Comment: Rotating 72° for five times gives you...?

Comment: Smart. I understand Lord Soth's answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a rotation matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos t &-\sin t\\\sin t&\cos t\end{pmatrix}$$
that does counterclockwise rotation on the usual $xy$-plane by an angle of $t$. Now, put $t=2\pi/5$ to get what you want (Rotating $5$ times by an angle of $2\pi/5$ should mean no rotation (and thus an identity matrix)).

Answer (score 6):

We can identify a complex number $a+ib$ by the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}$$ Can you find $z\in\Bbb C$ such that $z^5=1$?

Comment: The question asks about a real matrix though.

Comment: @Grid $a$ and $b$ are (implicitly) real.

Comment: The matrix will be real, @Grid since we're using $\Re z$ and $\Im z$.

Comment: One z would be (-1)^(2/5) which is approximately 0.309 + 0.951i so the a would be around .309 and cos(72°) is approximately .309, so this seems intimately related to the rotations.

Comment: @Grid Of course. $e^{i\theta}$ rotates complex numbers. Do you know that $\omega_k=e^{2\pi i k/5}$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4$ is such that $\omega_k^5=1$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks. Vaguely knew the connections, but makes much more sense when explicitly written out.